# There is already an account 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, database, debugging, customer-registration

I'm having following issue that i'm not able to reproduce https://ibb.co/0M1mvQ6
I checked in system.log but i don't have any critical warning.
I made also a registration with a different email address and worked correctly
Only sometimes seems that is error is triggered.. Do you have any idea about this?
Thanks

Comment: This error mentioned you are trying to register with an Existing email. Which is already registered as a customer. You can check the registered customers email on table customer_entity

Comment: yes but i have already 5 users told me this problem. I don't think that all of them wrote an existing email..

Comment: if its a live website, get the customer tried email and verify it with the database table, with that hope you can find something.